# java socket and DoS

Tags: java, sockets, ddos

I wrote a little java program that establishes a socket connection (port 23456) over TCP between a server (pong.java) and a client (ping.java). I start the server and then the client which sends ping and the server responds with pong. This happens 50 times.

This works all fine but now i want to shut this down using a SYN Flood DoS attack with hping3, but i can't get it to work. I can easily stop a file transfer running between the client and the server over SMB with the same DoS program. The server definitely gets the SYN packages- When i attack the same port the java socket connection uses it just shuts the attack down and the java program happily finishes the 50 loops. i can't figure out why. is there some protection in java or do sockets in java work different than a TCP exchange over SMB?

I do this for a network class and i just can't figure it out. I just attack myself between 3 VMs so no one will get harmed.

I can provide the source code or further information if needed.

Thanks a lot if anyone can help.

Comment: Java doesn't do anything special, it just uses OS socket API

Comment: why do you think it doesn't work or what can i do to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it fits or not, however I wrote a server-client app and more clients were trying to connect. As long as I used the Sun JRE, it worked. With the OpenJava, I was unable to get it work - only the first client connected, the others had to wait. I was unable to figure out why, and didn't really care - installed Sun (nowadays Oracle) JRE on the server and it run smooth. So if you use Linux and OpenJava, I suggest give it a try with Oracle's JRE.

Comment: unfortunately i run it on two windows XP VMs and only the attacker is ubuntu

Comment: Hard to believe. You must have been doing something pretty strange.